# How to calculate alternating double sum

Tags: summation

How do I determine the value of the following alternating sum (converges by Leibniz):

$$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{2n}{2n\choose k}(-1)^k (p)^{k+1},\quad p \in (0, 1)
$$

I don't have any idea how one can tackle such a sum as I just started learning about them.

Comment: Hint: replace $(-1)^k$ by $\pm(-1)^{n-k}$ and make $(1-p)^n$ binomial expansion appear. Are you sure it is $2n$ ?

Comment: @zwim it's funny that you propose that because that's exactly what the some looked like at first, and then I transformed it in the above while hoping this would make it easier

Comment: ah, I see, I made some mistake at first, thanks!

Comment: Then set $r=1-p$ and $\sum r^n$ is the sum of a geometric series.

Comment: @zwim yes, that's what I did!

Answer (score 3):

$$ S= \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{2n}{2n\choose k}(-1)^k (p)^{k+1}$$
$$ \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{2n}{2n\choose k}(-1)^k (p)^{k+1}= p~(1-p)^{2n} $$
$$ S = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} p~(1-p)^{2n} = p \cdot \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} (1-p)^{2n}  $$
$$p \in (0, 1) \implies 1-p \in (0, 1) $$
Now, all that's left is the sum of an infinite geometric progression with common ratio $ (1-p)^2 \in (0, 1)$